# I'm trying to set up a reverse proxy with XAMPP

Tags: xampp, reverse-proxy, virtualhost

im trying to setup a reverse proxy with XAMPP
I added omega.epicfailgu.co.uk to my CNAME on go daddy
and i setup my httpd-vhosts.conf as follows

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs"
    ServerName www.epicfailgu.co.uk
    ServerAdmin webmaster@epicfailgu.co.uk
    ErrorLog "C:/xampp/apache/logs/error.log"
    TransferLog "C:/xampp/apache/logs/access.log"
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:8081>
    ServerName omega.epicfailgu.co.uk
    ProxyPreserveHost on
    ProxyPass / http://localhost:8081/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8081/

<Proxy *>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
        Authtype Basic
        Authname "Password Required"
        AuthUserFile C:\xampp\.htpasswd
        Require valid-user
</Proxy>

</VirtualHost>
```

but if I go to omega.epicfailgu.co.uk it just points to my main website at [www.epicfailgu.co.uk](http://www.epicfailgu.co.uk)

I actually want it to point to a localhost control pannel running on port 8081 and I also need it to be password protected